# Android - High frequency background task

Tags: android, multithreading, background, task

I need to implement a background task that needs to update the UI about every 10 seconds. I tried the following approaches, but most of them failed.

1) AlarmManager

I started an intent service via AlarmManager. It seems that AlarmManager is only suitable for very low frequencies, like several hours. If I set it to 10 seconds, then the UI does not respond anymore. Why is that? Doesn't the intent service run in a separate thread?

2) IntentService with infinite loop and Thread.sleep

App was terminated after about 30 seconds, UI was not responding at all. Is intent service only for very short background tasks? I found contradicting information about this. Why is the UI not responding although intent service should run in a separate thread?

3) AsyncTask

When using AsyncTask, the UI remains responsive. But for some reasons, no other AsyncTask is started from the UI. I heard about some limits of concurrend AsyncTasks, but 2 should not be too much?

4) Own Threads

That worked. Background service and UI are fully functional. However, I read that it is bad practise to use threads directly when updating the UI. What would be the best way in this context to send data to the Activity?

What do you recommend for a background task that needs to update the UI and reoccures about every 10 seconds?

Best regards!

Comment: "If I set it to 10 seconds, then the UI does not respond anymore. Why is that?" -- because you have a bug in your code. "Why is the UI not responding although intent service should run in a separate thread?" -- because you have a bug in your code. "I heard about some limits of concurrend AsyncTasks, but 2 should not be too much?" -- `AsyncTask` is serialized on Android 3.2+ with a `targetSdkVersion` of 13 or higher. See "Order of Execution" in [the `AsyncTask` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: "I read that it is bad practise to use threads directly when updating the UI" -- updating a `View` from a background thread usually results in a crash. Presumably, you are doing something to get around this (e.g., `runOnUiThread()`), or are only updating widgets that are safe to update on a background thread (e.g., `ProgressBar`). "What do you recommend..." -- that depends on other information, such as what should happen when the user navigates away from your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare `CommonsWare` is answering in a very specific way to your questions. I would recommend you to ask him now: `Why do i have a bug` and of course provide code:)

Comment: @Mike: I cannot tell the OP why the OP has a bug in the code, as I cannot see the OP's code. There are any number of possible ways of screwing up inter-thread communication in Java, let alone with Android's main application thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare i know, it shouldn't be offensive. I really like the way you are answering questions. And if someone asks you the right questions, he gets very good informations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the task to happen in recurring fashion, i would think Alarm Manager is better option.

These are my reasons.

1. It allows you to fire Intents at set times and/or intervals.
2. We can use them in conjunction with broadcast receivers to start services and perform other operations even **when your app is not running, and even if the device itself is asleep**.
3. They help you to minimize your app's resource requirements. **You can schedule operations without relying on timers or continuously running background services.**

As per android documentation,

> For timing operations that are guaranteed to occur during the lifetime
>   of your application, instead consider using the Handler class in
>   conjunction with Timer and Thread. This approach gives Android better
>   control over system resources.